# Secure ASP.Net Core 3.1 API with Bearer Tokens from Azure AD

Tags: c#, security, jwt, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a .net core 3.1 web API.  I want to secure the endpoints using bearer tokens from Azure AD.

I have followed [This guide](https://dotnetplaybook.com/secure-a-net-core-api-using-bearer-authentication).  I have a registered an app for the API and an app for the client.

In my API, I have added a registration for the jwt (as outlined in the code)

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(opt =>
    {
        opt.Audience = Configuration["AzureAd:ResourceId"];
        opt.Authority = $"{Configuration["AzureAd:Instance"]}{Configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"]}";
    });
```

And my configuration section for the API looks like this

```
"AzureAd": {
    "ResourceId": "api://<client-id-guid>",
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "TenantId": "<tenant-id-guid>"
}
```

where the `client-id-guid` is the client id of the api application (used the default configuration for the api:// address).

Then, for my client, I implemented a test in a new solution to get the token and call a secured endpoint.

```
AadConfiguration config = AadConfiguration.ReadFromJsonFile("appsettings.json");

IConfidentialClientApplication app;

app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(config.ClientId)
    .WithClientSecret(config.ClientSecret)
    .WithAuthority(new Uri(config.Authority))
    .Build();

string[] ResourceIds = new string[] {config.ResourceID};

var token = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(ResourceIds)
    .ExecuteAsync();

Assert.IsFalse(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token.AccessToken));

var request = new RestRequestBuilder("https://my-api-staging.azurewebsites.net/api")
    .WithSegments("health-check", "auth")
    .WithBearerToken(token.AccessToken)
    .Build();

try
{
    var response = await _restHelper.GetJsonAsync<dynamic>(request);

    Assert.IsFalse(string.IsNullOrEmpty(response?.serverTime?.ToString()));
}
catch (RestException e)
{
    Assert.IsFalse(true, e.ResponseContent);
}
```

And the configuration for this test

```
{
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}",
    "TenantId": "<tenant-id-guid>",
    "ClientId": "<client-id-guid>",
    "ClientSecret": "<client-secret>",
    "ResourceId": "api://<api-client-id-guid>/.default"
}
```

Tenant Id is the sale for both the API and the test application

The client ID is the client id for the client app registration, and its secret

The resource Id is the API's application id, which is the api:// with the api's client Id

I can retrieve the access token just fine.  However, when I call an endpoint using the access token I am given, I get the following error:

> Couldn't find a valid certificate with subject 'CN=TODO.azurewebsites.net' on the 'CurrentUser\My'

I'm not sure why my authentication is failing when I have followed the steps in the document.

Comment: Where does that error come up? Is it on the client or the API?

Comment: It's in the client, when calling the secured endpoint in the API.

Comment: If you take the token and make the HTTP request with something else, does it work?

Comment: Using postman, I get the same error.  I also have two tests in my code, one like the above, and one where I manually build the rest request.  All three methods return the same error.

Comment: The error sounds a bit like the request is trying to use client certificate authentication.. Is that configured on the target API?

Comment: There are no certificates assigned to either app registration.  They are created from scratch exactly as the guide said to make them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I can retrieve the access token just fine. However, when I call an endpoint using the access token I am given, I get the following error:

I follow the [guide](https://dotnetplaybook.com/secure-a-net-core-api-using-bearer-authentication/) and test in my site which works very well.

After getting access token, you can try to use it in postman to send request to core api. While the core api is 3.1 version, so it do not have `/api` to route it.

[image]

And you can use `HttpClient` to call core webapi.

```
var token = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(ResourceIds).ExecuteAsync();
var accesstoken = token.AccessToken;
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accesstoken);
    var requestURl = new Uri($"https://xxxx.azurewebsites.net/weatherforecast");
    var response = client.GetAsync(requestURl).Result;
    string result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}
```

[image]

Comment: When I use postman, I get the above exception.  Couldn't find a valid certificate with subject 'CN=TODO.azurewebsites.net' on the 'CurrentUser\My'. Same if I go to the base url of the application (it's running in an app service in azure).

Comment: I test  in my postman using local url with http and it also work well. I suggest to decode your access token to check whether the aud is same with your core api reourceId.

Comment: I follow the guide and work well. Try to check the tutorial again to avoid missing some details.